# What does the # symbol mean in documentation (example: Cache#get(key[, options]))

Tags: javascript

In the [docs for angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache#cachegetkey-options), the author uses this nomenclature:

> **Cache#get(key[, options])**
>
> Return the item with the given key. options, if provided, must be an
>   object.
>
> If the cache is in passive mode, then options.onExpire can be a
>   function that will be called with the key and value of the requested
>   item if the requested item is expired, with the get call itself
>   returning undefined.

The function is called simply by `Cache.get(key)`.  So what does the `#`, and why is it used?

Comment: It denotes a method that belongs to the class and is static (in this case)?\

Comment: Perhaps the developers have gotten caught up with Twitter?  #notfunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes can have static methods and prototype methods.

Static methods are available on the class itself, and prototype methods are inherited by the instances of the class.

For example, with arrays,

- `Array.from` is a static method. Using it on instances like `[].from` won't work.
- `Array.prototype.slice` is a prototype method. You can use it on instances like `[].slice`

To avoid writing `prototype`, some people use the `#` notation to refer to prototype methods. In the example above, they would say `Array#slice`. Note this notation is only used when talking about JavaScript, but you can't use it in the code itself.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Does this belong over here, also?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript

Comment: @cale_b Not sure, because in fact it's not JS syntax. Maybe it could be called meta-syntax